# Disable Scrolling inside mapView but want marker pins should be clicked or enabled iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, mkmapview

I want to disable scrolling inside mapView but `GMSMarker` pins should be clickable.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Is it Android or iOS?

Comment: it is iOS @AsifHabib

Answer (score 0):

For `MKMapView`

```
mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

For Google Map

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for my problem ....

Best way is to set :

mapView_.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

and add a button on superview and add a target to it :)